# Can Siri add some form of timestamp to a Note?

Tags: ios, text, notes.app, siri

I'd like Siri to add a timestamp -- I'm not too fussy about the exact format -- of the current day and time to the end of one of my notes in the Notes app. She can find the note just fine, but takes me too literally:

"Add the current date and time to my UFO Sightings note"

> **Okay, I updated your note:**
>
> UFO Sightings
>   Jun 3    11:18
>   Jun 5    11:28
>   The current date and time

In hopes of getting some guidance, I then tried

"Can you add a timestamp to one of my notes?"

She asked which one, and when I told her, she cheerfully replied

> **Okay, I updated your note:**
>
> UFO Sightings
>   Jun 3    11:18
>   Jun 5    11:28
>   The current date and time
>   A timestamp

I asked about her capabilities in general, too, and got a list of example commands, but it didn't seem exhaustive at all:

[image]

Is there a command I haven't been able to find? I'm willing to use this as an excuse to finally buy TextExpander (or similar) if necessary, though I'd prefer a built-in method.

I'm on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not currently possible using Siri. If on iOS 12 a Shortcut can be made by downloading the Shortcuts app from the App Store.

You can then make this Shortcut:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

You can format the date and time as you wish. You can record a phrase for Siri to copy this to the clipboard. After this you’ll need to manually paste it in the note.

---

<sup>Images from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250089354</sup>

Comment: Nice! I had forgotten about this question, but in fact I used Workflow (predecessor to Shortcuts) to achieve my goal. I used a different notes app that has a URL scheme allowing appending to a specific named note.

Comment: @JoshCaswell cool! I’ll keep my answer here in case it helps anyone. PS: Why don’t you post an answer as to what you did to help someone else with a similar problem?